# Using appMobi can I create Android apps and iPhone apps for free (besides Google/Apple costs)?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cross-platform, appmobi

In a *quest* for an answer whether to go for native iPhone development Vs hybrid HTML5/CSS/JS development (coming from some Android experience), I'd like to understand the following about [appMobi](http://www.appmobi.com/) framework:

1. With appMobi XDK, which I can download for free, and **without** paying any particular online service, will I be able to build and obtain an Android package ready for Android Market, and an iPhone package ready for AppStore?
2. Same question as before, but with PhoneGap XDK: download it for free, no cloud services fee, and still be able to obtain app packages ready for respective stores?

I've been through several appMobi tutorials, FAQ and forum threads. But those two points are not really clear to me anyway. I must say I started to look at this just during the days appMobi was going through quite a change (open sourcing, free/paid online build, etc.) so I've found some contrasting fresh/old information at the time. I've also digged here on SO, but with no luck.

I understand that their pricing is actually not that *exaggerated*, but at the moment I'd like to try out the whole *journey* from development up to publishing on store. I might go for paid services later on.

**Edit:**
For clarification, here I'm not considering Google/Apple marketplace subscription costs. When I say *free* I'm referring just to the appMobi side of things.

TA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ian from AppMobi here.  Hopefully I can answer your questions.

First, Google and Appple have their own costs to submit to the app store.  For Android, it's $25, for iOS it's $99.  These are a requirement to submit to the appstores and not associated with AppMobi.  If you were to use the native SDK's or any other tool, you are still required to pay these costs.

Now, for the cost of AppMobi. If you are using the AppMobi XDK (not Phonegap or GameXDK), then the cost to build is nothing.  You can build an Android or iOS app for free.  What we charge for is cloud services, like push messaging, stats, etc.

PhonegapXDK and GameXDK do require what we call "pro packs" to build.  This is because we offer additional functionality not found in our base XDK or base containers.

Comment: thanks for your answer Ian. You are correct to separate Google/Apple stores costs from appMobi. Actually I was not considering those, I am aware of them. I was more interested in just the appMobi side, and I'll make it more clear in the question as a future reference.

Comment: I've looked [here](http://www.appmobi.com/?q=node/153) and [here](http://www.appmobi.com/?q=node/137) but I could not figure out the PhonegapXDK Pro Pack costs. Could you please post a link? Tnx again.

Comment: I have no idea why we don't have it listed on the site.  I know when you go to build, it will tell you.  It's $99 a year for 5 apps (unlimitted builds) or $19.99 a month.  You also get 1 block each of our cloud services per month.  Log in at http://enterprise.appmobi.com/csd/phonegappro.aspx to see it.

Comment: last check: with PhoneGapXDK, is there a way to obtain iPhone/Android packages for free, e.g. by building locally on Mac/whatever?

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to pay anything for Android market. But you still need to pay $99 for Apple developer program to push your iPhone app in App store.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but for completeness: Android Market requires 25$ one time subscription (Apple is 99$/ year).